# How to create and register a new UI element for some type in properties?

Tags: c#, xaf

Consider I have this entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public Address PersonAddress { get; set; }
}
```

which `Address` is a `ComplexType`:

```
public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street {get; set; }
}
```

So in database I have `PersonAddress_City`, `PersonAddress_Street` columns.

**Question 1:** The Model Designer doesn't show this ComplexType properties. How can I use them in the application?

**Question 2:** How can I design a custom control and tell XAF to use it for properties of type `Address`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure PersonAddress will be shown in Model Designer, if Address class descends from a base XPO class, like XPCustomObject.

By default, it will be a LookupPropertyEditor (a combo) in UI. You can either [create a custom control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112679) for it, or expand the Adresss members into the Person DetailView, with the built-in  [ExpandObjectMembersAttribute](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/DevExpressPersistentBaseExpandObjectMembersEnumtopic).

Comment: ExpandObjectMembersAttribute should also work with Entity Framework (at least it is not XPO dependent).